# Table not found in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

My problem is when runnng the app with sqlite the error log show from

final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

```
    String Query=("SELECT * FROM sekolah");

    cursor=db.rawQuery(Query,null);

    if (cursor !=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());cursor.close();
    }
```

**cursor=db.rawQuery(Query,null);**

on My MainActivity.java

**and error log show Like this** [Eror log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9zfs.png)

Comment: And why do you think that this table exists?

Comment: in eror log show that table didnt exists

Comment: That is not what I asked. Why do you think that the error message is a problem? Doesn't your app create the table?

Comment: that table was created but show error lihe that

Comment: Why do you think the table was created?